# Cooking tied-up ribeye

Tags: grilling, steak, barbecue

This is probably a silly question, but I saw these steaks that the butcher in the grocery store said to be made of several pieces attached together by a thread. So I am wondering:

- How do you cook a tied-up ribeye?
- Can it be done on a grill?
- Should the thread be removed before grilling or after?

My concern is that if the thread is removed before grilling the whole thing might just fall apart. The steaks looked delicious and I'd love to cook those, but I have no idea how to handle the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cook it with the string on, then remove the string when you eat it. It is there to hold it altogether while cooking. Should be fine to grill, butcher's twine is food safe and stands up to roasting and braising so should be fine on the grill too. But if you wanted to do something else, like turn the smaller pieces into kabobs, then you could skewer them with some veggies and grill them.

At least your butcher was honest about tying the pieces together with string. I bought a vaccum packed ribeye "steak" the other day and when I was grilling it and turned it, the top part came off as a thin slice like roladen.